# Clone for all-Clone structures with a non-Clone type parameter

Tags: rust

I am using a `#[derive(Clone)]` for `struct<T>` where `T` is not `Clone` but all the elements of the struct are `Clone` (since `Rc<T>` is always `Clone`). How, if at all, can I convince Rust to derive the trait for me?

A working example: [(playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=863a0662fafe674f03307880fa8bbe54&version=stable&backtrace=0)

```
use std::rc::Rc;

struct NotClone;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct WithRc<T> {
    elem: Rc<T>
    // ...
}

impl<T> WithRc<T> {
    pub fn new(v: T) -> WithRc<T> {
        WithRc { elem: Rc::new(v) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = WithRc::new(NotClone { });
    let b = a.clone(); // This triggers the error
}
```

The error message is

```
error: no method named `clone` found for type `WithRc<NotClone>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:19:15
   |
19 |     let b = a.clone(); // This triggers the error
   |               ^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `clone` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `NotClone : std::clone::Clone`
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope; the following trait defines an item `clone`, perhaps you need to implement it:
   = help: candidate #1: `std::clone::Clone`
```

[This doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) indicates that having `Clone` members should be enough (and that would make sense), but maybe I am missing something.

I know I *could* implement `Clone` myself, but since I already use `WithRc<T>` as a thin wrapper around a `Rc`-wrapped data structure where some methods need the shared pointer to self, I'm trying to avoid more boilerplate.

Comment: *How, if at all, can I convince Rust to derive the trait for me?* — you cannot.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for the pointer to the other question. I must have missed it as it does not mention Clone in the name (but is Clone-specific).

Comment: The code in the question uses `Clone`, but the problem is due to using `derive`. Any parameterized type will have that issue with any derived trait.